# Why can’t one see for 2nd order system that it is at its stability limit neither in the Nyquist plot nor Bode plot?

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory

Consider $$\hat{G}(s) = \frac{1}{s^2+s}$$
than the Nyquist plot is
[image: nyquist plot]

and the Bode plot is
[image: Bode Plot]

In both plots it seems that the closed-loop system is stable even when the eigenvalues are {0, -1}. For a higher order closed-loop system one can see that a system like

$$\hat{G}(s) = \frac{1}{s^3+s^2+s}$$

is at its stability limit since ne Nquist plots hits the real axis at -1 and in the Bode plot there is no phase reserve when magnitude hits 0. Why dose the Nyquist and the Bode plot fail for a closed-loop system of 2nd order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are mixing up the closed- and open-loop systems.

The closed-loop system is $$\frac{\frac{1}{s^2+s}}{1+\frac{1}{s^2+s}}=\frac{1}{s^2+s+1}$$

This has poles at $-0.5\pm 0.866025 i$ which is stable.

Comment: Am i only allowed to view the plots for closed-loops?

Comment: The Nyquist stability criterion and things like gain and phase margin that are seen on the Bode plot are for the closed-loop system. The utility of these plots is that you can get insights into the closed-loop behavior using the open-loop transfer function.

Comment: I don't get your point, so let the open-loop system be $\frac{1}{s^2+s-1}$ so the closed on is $\frac{1}{s^2+s}$ now the eigenvalues of the closed one are still {0, -1} but my bode plot still shows a phase reserve of 51.8 deg when the magnitude hits 0

Comment: For $\frac{1}{s^2+s-1}$, when the magnitude is 0 db, the phase is -180 degrees. The phase margin is 0.

Comment: but not in the matlab plot above

Comment: Please get the basics right w.r.t closed- and open-loop systems, or we will be repeating the same thing over and over. In the matlab plot (as I explained in the answer) the open loop is $\frac{1}{s^2+1}$ which gives a stable closed-loop. With the open-loop of $\frac{1}{s^2+s-1}$ the closed-loop is marginally stable. This is what the plots confirm.

Comment: hang on, does this mean the matlab function nyquist() and bode() expect the open-loop system. i was thinking i had to give it the closed-loop system. so my problem was been new to matlab nyquist- and bode-functions. sorry for wasting your time and thank you.

Comment: Bingo. Yes, when you are doing stability analysis, computing stability margins, and so on, you analyze the frequency response of the open-loop system. Thus, the open-loop transfer function needs to be used for Nyquist and Bode plots. The results will tell you something about the closed-loop system.